Issue with circular reference infinite loop when doing BFS on a multidimensional matrix
When doing a Breadth First Search on a Multidimensional Matrix where some cells are blocked, I am getting a circular reference and going into an infinite loop.
How would I backtrack my BFS search to return a path from Node B to node S?

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] grid = {
            {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'o'},
            {'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'B'},
            {'s', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'o'},
            {'x', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o'},
            {'x', 'o', 'x', 'x', 'o'}
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}


public class BFS{
   public List<Cell> breadthFirstSearch(Cell bot, Cell button, Fire fire){
        int row = ship.getSize(); //I've hardcoded an example matrix
        int col = ship.getSize();

        Queue <Cell> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue <Cell> visited = new LinkedList<>();
        Cell[][] parent = new Cell[ship.getSize()][ship.getSize()];
        //Map <Cell, Cell> parent = new HashMap<>(); // Stores child, parent
        boolean matchFound = false;

        //Starting Node
        queue.add(bot);
        visited.add(bot);
        parent[bot.getX()][bot.getY()] = null;
        Cell previous = null;
        Cell current = null;

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){        

            // Assign current node & Moves to next cell in queue
            previous = current;
            current = queue.poll();
            System.out.println("LOOP Current : " + current.toString());

            // Check if bot = button
            if(current.equals(button)){
                parent[current.getX()][current.getY()] = previous;
                List<Cell> path = new ArrayList<>();
                Cell node = new Cell(current.getX(), current.getY());
                Cell prevNode = null;
                //path.add(node);
                while(node != null){
                    path.add(node);
                    node = parent[node.getX()][node.getY()];
                    System.out.print("CurrentNODE: " + node);           
                }
                Collections.reverse(path);
                return path;
            }
            
            //Add children of bot to queue
            else{
                for(Cell neighbor : getBotNeighbors(current)){
                    //System.out.println(neighbor);
                    if((!(ship.isBurning(neighbor.getX(),neighbor.getY()))) && 
                    (neighbor.isOpenCell(ship))){
                        if (!visited.contains(neighbor)) {
                            queue.add(neighbor);
                            visited.add(neighbor);
                        }
                        parent[current.getX()][current.getY()]= neighbor;
                        //System.out.println("parent (key): " + current.toString() + "; (value): " + parent.get(current));
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}


I want to go from nodeB to nodeS and for some reason even though it is finding the correct path, it is stuck in an infinite loop when backtracking.

Hello yay, welcome, Perhaps, you are missing the use of the variable matchFound...

Your main code just prints a matrix. That's all. But this code does not even compile. Please provide that compiles and reproduces the problem.

Figured it out- wanted to post for anyone else :p
public class Bot_1 extends Bot{

public Bot_1(Ship ship){
    super(ship);
}

public List<Cell> breadthFirstSearch(Ship ship, Cell hProbCell){

    Cell bot = new Cell(ship.getBot().getX(), ship.getBot().getY());
    Cell dest = new Cell(hProbCell.getX(), hProbCell.getY());
    Queue <Cell> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    boolean visited[][] = new boolean[ship.getSize()][ship.getSize()];
    Cell[][] parent = new Cell[ship.getSize()][ship.getSize()];
    Cell[][] cells = new Cell[ship.getSize()][ship.getSize()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ship.getSize(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ship.getSize(); j++) {
            if (ship.isOpenCell(i,j)) {
                cells[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, Integer.MAX_VALUE, null);
            }
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    //Starting Node
    queue.add(cells[bot.getX()][bot.getY()]);
    visited[bot.getX()][bot.getY()] = true;
    parent[bot.getX()][bot.getY()] = null;
    Cell current = null;
    Cell previous = null;

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){

        // Assign current node & Moves to next cell in queue
        previous = current;
        current = queue.poll();

        // Check if bot = button
        if(current.equals(dest)){
            List<Cell> path = new ArrayList<>();
            Cell node = current;
            if (node.getParentCell() == null || node == null) {
                Collections.reverse(path);
                return path;
            }
            else {
                while(node.getParentCell() != null){
                    path.add(node);
                    node = node.getParentCell();
                }
                Collections.reverse(path);
                return path;
            }
        }
        //Add children of bot to queue
        else{
            for(Cell neighbor : getBotNeighbors(current)){
                if((neighbor.isOpenCell(ship)) && visited[neighbor.getX()][neighbor.getY()] == false){
                    int dist = current.getDist() + 1;
                    if (dist < neighbor.getDist()) {
                        visited[neighbor.getX()][neighbor.getY()] = true;
                        cells[neighbor.getX()][neighbor.getY()].setDist(dist);
                        cells[neighbor.getX()][neighbor.getY()].setParentCell(cells[current.getX()][current.getY()]);
                        queue.add(cells[neighbor.getX()][neighbor.getY()]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No path exists between bot and button.");
    return new ArrayList<>();
}

}

Maybe you could indicate what changes you made in the code and why those changes fixed your problem?
